# Multiple Flutter animation not working one after the other

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter, at the moment I am trying to make a simple app where when the APP is opened a Text appears with `fadeIn` and changes its `position from bottom to top`. Yes, there are two `animations` which I want to `Transit`. The first one is `FadeIn` after it is completed goes and carries on with the next `animation` which is `Position Transition` which changes the `Vertical` position of the Text from `400.0` to `200.0 pixels.`

I was able to achieve the fadeIn process but position one is not being applied.
First I want the FadeIn TextAnimation to start after it's done I want to start the PositionAnimation, not at the same time but one after the other when the animations complete.

Here is the code:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
 with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 AnimationController animationController;
 double position = 400.0;
 Animation<double> _animation;
 Tween<double> tween;

  @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();

    animationController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
  );

   _animation = CurvedAnimation(
   parent: animationController,
   curve: Curves.easeIn,
 );

   tween = Tween(begin: 400, end: 200);

   animationController.forward();
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
    body: FadeTransition(
      opacity: _animation,

      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical:_animation.isCompleted? tween : position,
            horizontal: 180.0),
        child: Text(
          'My Life',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 30.0,
              color: Colors.white70,
              letterSpacing: 2.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

 @override
  void dispose() {
  animationController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
 }
}
```

Any expertise, Since I am new I am not sure what I did wrong. Please guide me, anyone.

Here is the updated code which I have tried today but still I am not getting the result:

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
  with TickerProviderStateMixin {
AnimationController animationControllerFade;
AnimationController animationControllerPost;
double position = 400.0;
FadeTransition fadeTransition;
Animation<double> animation;
int i = 0;

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();

   animationControllerFade = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
   );
   animationControllerPost = AnimationController(
     vsync: this,
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
   );

   animation = CurvedAnimation(
     parent: animationControllerFade,
     curve: Curves.easeIn,
   );

   animationControllerFade.forward();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Scaffold sc;
   sc = Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
   );

   fadeTransition = FadeTransition(
     opacity: animation,
     child: paddingOwn(position),
   );

   animationControllerFade.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
       animationControllerPost.forward();
       sc = Scaffold(
          body: TweenAnimationBuilder(
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 400.0, end: 200.0),
          builder: (BuildContext context, double val, Widget child) {
            return Positioned(child: paddingOwn(val));
           },
          ),
        );
       } 
       else {
          sc = Scaffold(body: fadeTransition);
       }
     });

     return sc;
   }

   Widget paddingOwn(double val) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: val,
        horizontal: 180,
      ),
      child: Text(
        'My Life',
        style: TextStyle(
           fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
           fontSize: 30.0,
           color: Colors.white70,
           letterSpacing: 2.0),
      ),
     );
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      animationControllerFade.dispose();
      animationControllerPost.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
   }
```

still not result.

Comment: Still no result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the position transition, you need to use `SlideTransition`.

Also, you need to animate the `Tween` in order to get the values interpolated properly.

I changed a little your code in order to center the text and animate it from there. Anyway, just keep in mind that `SlideTransition` works with [Offsets in a relative way from the size of the child](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SlideTransition-class.html)

Now, you should be able to adapt this code to the final result you want to achieve:

```dart
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _fadeAnimationController;
  AnimationController _slideAnimationController;
  double position = 400.0;
  Animation<double> _fadeAnimation;
  Animation<Offset> _slideAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _fadeAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    );

    _slideAnimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
    );

    _fadeAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _fadeAnimationController,
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );

    _slideAnimation = Tween(begin: Offset(0, 0), end: Offset(0, -3)).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _slideAnimationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    ));

    _play();
  }

  Future<void> _play() async {
    try {
      await _fadeAnimationController.forward().orCancel;
      await _slideAnimationController.forward().orCancel;
    } on TickerCanceled {
      //Handle if animation was canceled for whatever reason if you need it
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Center(
        child: SlideTransition(
          position: _slideAnimation,
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: _fadeAnimation,
            child: Text(
              'My Life',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white70, letterSpacing: 2.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _fadeAnimationController.dispose();
    _slideAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Update:**

You are not seeing changes with your padding because you have two mistakes:

- You are not animating the tween
- You are using `symmetric`, that adds the same margin from both sides.

To solve the tween thing, you need to add something like this:

```dart
tween = Tween(begin: 400, end: 200).animate(animationController);
```

To solve the padding thing, you can use `only`, to apply the *padding* only in one side:

```dart
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: tween)
```

Comment: I have tried with the `Animation<Offset>` it seems there is no error when I run but I only get blank Screen

Comment: The comment I pasted here works fine. Have you try It?

Comment: I updated my comment with more information about your problem.

Comment: I have tried and I got an error saying that `Tween Double can't be assigned to parameter type double`. I just change that Tween thing with adding `.animate(animationController)`, and at the padding just as you said `EdgeInserts.only(tween)`

Comment: along with that also another error `_AnimatedEvaluation<double>' is not a subtype of type 'Tween<double>' in type cast` which I am not able to understand it.

Comment: I have added `as Tween<double>` in tween, it was suggesting to cast it with a red underline.

Comment: I have updated the code which I have tried today but still I am not able to get the result which I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you replaced the entire code I pasted here? I just copied and pasted the one that works for me without issues. Flutter 2.x

Comment: I have just used it as a reference.

Comment: I have tried just now and it is so near.. I guess I better tweak a little in your code. :D

Comment: can I do like this first I want to complete the `fadeIn Animation` then after that start the `other animation`. because the code which I have updated where I tried to use the listener to check the status of the Widget and then reacted to it. Still not result???

Comment: Sorry, you were right. I changed the code in the response to reflect what you are looking for. Look at "play" method, you are now able to run animations sequentially. Copy & paste the code and modify it to get the result you want